# Repeating Command in LLDB

Tags: c++, debugging, repeat, lldb

How can I repeatedly run a command in LLDB for debugging C++ code?

For example, when I set a breakpoint inside a loop and want to continue for 10 iterations before stopping, I am currently typing `continue` ten times manually to do this. Is there a better way?

As an example, let's say I have this code block:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
  // Increment i
  i++;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line with the comment, I could keep using the command `continue` to go through one iteration of the loop and go back to that line. However, if I wanted to skip over 10 iterations (i.e. use the command `continue` 10 times), how would I do that?

Comment: With gdb you could just do `c 10`, but I don't think lldb supports this.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this and unfortunately it does not work. Thank you for the suggestion though! If I cannot figure this out, I might just switch to gdb, since manually repeating commands would be really annoying!

Comment: I'm hoping someone will come back and answer this question. I'm pleased the OP got what they needed but it doesn't answer the question in the title and first sentence. I'd like to know the easiest way to run an arbitrary command 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lldb tends to use options where gdb would use a command argument.  That makes it easier to have a bunch of different ways to condition a particular command without having to come up with ad hoc mini-syntaxes for each command.

Anyway, so in lldb you would do:

```
(lldb) c -i 10
```

You can see this in help:

```
(lldb) help continue
Continue execution of all threads in the current process.

Syntax: continue <cmd-options>

Command Options Usage:
  continue [-i <unsigned-integer>]

       -i <unsigned-integer> ( --ignore-count <unsigned-integer> )
            Ignore <N> crossings of the breakpoint (if it exists) for the currently selected thread.

'continue' is an abbreviation for 'process continue'
```

Note also that you can do the same thing just by setting the ignore count in the breakpoint you just hit: `break modify -i 10 <BKPTNO>`.

Comment: BTW, `continue 10` isn't really a general command repeat, it just skips the next 10 hits of the breakpoint you are currently stopped at.  It doesn't even strictly "repeat" the continue command 10 times, since if you hit another breakpoint it will stop.  It's really just syntactic  sugar for setting the ignore count on the breakpoint you stopped at and continuing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a conditional breakpoint. In gdb it's like this

> - `break ... if cond`
>
>   - Set a breakpoint with condition `cond`; evaluate the expression `cond` each time the breakpoint is reached, and stop only if the value is nonzero--that is, if `cond` evaluates as true. `...' stands for one of the possible arguments described above (or no argument) specifying where to break. See section [Break conditions](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_33.html#SEC34), for more information on breakpoint conditions.
>
> https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html

For example if `i` is currently 0 and you want to break on line 10 then use

```
break 10 if i >= 10
```

Just increase the condition value based no the current value of `i`

I don't know `lldb` but according the the [mapping list](http://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html) `break foo if strcmp(y,"hello") == 0` in gdb can be done as the following in lldb

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --name foo --condition '(int)strcmp(y,"hello") == 0'
(lldb) br s -n foo -c '(int)strcmp(y,"hello") == 0'
```

If there's no loop counter you can just [declare a debug variable](http://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#evaluating-expressions) yourself

```
expr unsigned int $foo = 1
breakpoint set --name foo --condition '++$foo >= 10'
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What if the OP is has already hit that breakpoint several times before, and now wants to skip 10 times?

Comment: @cigien just add 10 to the current i value and it'll just forward 10 iterations

Comment: Well, that's true, but that loop is just an example. What if there's nothing in the loop that indicates when that breakpoint might be hit?

Comment: @cigien then just declare an lldb variable

Comment: How do I increment the debug variable though?

Comment: @ag2718 just evaluate it: `expr $foo++`. But I guess you just need to increase the variable while checking the condition

Comment: I tried this and found it a bit confusing, but I am new to LLDB, so thank you for the help! I think the other answer encapsulates what I was looking for in a more simple manner.